# Apache Error Log without reference error source page

Tags: php, apache, server

> File does not exist: /var/www/default/error

I keep receiving this error log inside my server while I don't have this file or folder. Normally when file is 404, I get the source page link like Reference www.example.com/error/error404.php. 
This one doesn't include this kind of information and I receive this message around 50-200 per 10 mili seconds from same IPs. So the error log file become super big within 3 days and now it become 5Gb already.

So, please give me some hints how to prevent this error and how to track where is this error coming from. Is it good idea to create a file or folder for this path? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a corresponding line with the same timestamp in access log?

Comment: Good point. I will check the access log. But it also become 10GB. So I might need an hour or two to download. :(

Comment: If you have ssh access to the server, you don't really have to download the whole file :)